# Rails - Ransack - search through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

User has_many profiles and profile has_many email address.
I have search form for User and I have field for email. How can I achieve this.

```
form_for @User.search do |U|
 f.text_field :name, :name_cont
 f.text_field :email, #what should I write here?
```

Comment: I think we need you to be a little more specific about what this form is supposed to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm unsure if this is the perfect way to do it. You can try adding a

`has_many :email, through: profiles` in the User model. After doing this, all you might have to do is, `:user_emails_cont`

Also try `:user_profiles_emails_cont`, without the has many through relationship.